# selecting a 3d model at runtime in vuforia augmented reality application

Tags: android, vuforia

i am working on augmented reality project using vuforia unity extension for android. I have a list of 3d models(.3ds). i want that when user select a model from that list than it is displayed in camera view. i don't have these model pre-loaded in the application. instead these can be in the memory card.
I searched on net but mostly the tutorials are about rendering .h using opengl at run time.
Is there any solution available for my problem? Please help me.

Comment: You can do this with some asset loader, example: http://assimp.sourceforge.net/
But the loading time is a bit slow

Answer (score 2):

The better option would to use a 3rd party 3D loader libraries. There are few libraries that provides integration with Vuforia.

JPCT - http://www.jpct.net/wiki/index.php/Integrating_JPCT-AE_with_Vuforia 
Rajawali - https://github.com/MasDennis/RajawaliVuforia

Answer (score 1):

You can not load 3d model after compilation of the code . because in vuforia .h class is used for the 3d model.You have to include that class before launching the application. at run time you will not ne able to compile that .h class. thats why all 3models should be preloaded as .h.